# Is there a shortcut to do JS imports in WebStorm?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm

I spend a lot of time writing JS imports.  Seems like WebStorm should be able to help me, but I can't find any shortcut for it.  Perhaps there is a plugin somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

There is a "Missing import statement" inspection that has a quickfix (available on `Alt+Enter`). Similar inspection is available for `require()`. See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/11/node-js-coding-assistance-in-webstorm-11/)